# Making a client page

Tags: login

I have done a bit of research and the answers have all come back "use a plugin". I don't want to do this for several reasons not least because most plugins have bloat and I'm perfectly capable of doing this in a lightweight fashion and the answer will stand for others.

1. the client can login from anywhere as a custom role `client`
2. when they login they are taken to a page `/clientusername` - created by admin
3. the page only contains material placed there by admin (i.e. there is no functionality for the client to edit the page)
4. if anyone else other than that client lands on that page (by typing in the url) they are redirected to the home page

---

```
function my_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ){
    if( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        if( $user->has_cap( 'client' ) ) {
                $client = $user->user_login;
                $url = home_url( $client, 'relative');
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

I realize there's a lot more to be done but I'll leave this here for discussion.

Comment: I may have written this function but I can't format my code above (please help)

Answer (score 1):

For the client role, use this;

```
    // Add a client user role

    $result = add_role( 'client', __(

    'Client' ),

    array(

        'read' => true, // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts' => false, // Allows user to edit their own posts
        'edit_pages' => false, // Allows user to edit pages
        'edit_others_posts' => false, // Allows user to edit others posts not just their own
        'create_posts' => false, // Allows user to create new posts
        'manage_categories' => false, // Allows user to manage post categories
        'publish_posts' => false, // Allows the user to publish, otherwise posts stays in draft mode
        'edit_themes' => false, // false denies this capability. User can’t edit your theme
        'install_plugins' => false, // User cant add new plugins
        'update_plugin' => false, // User can’t update any plugins
        'update_core' => false // user cant perform core updates

    )

);
```

and then use the code above to redirect the login if, and only if, it's a client role.

One the page template Client Page put this **before** `get_header()`:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$client = $current_user->user_login;
$slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );
$client = strtolower($client);
if ($client != $slug) {
    header("Location: /index.php");
}
```

and, obviously, we need to let admins see the page;

```
if (!current_user_can('administrator')) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $client = $current_user->user_login;
    $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );
    $client = strtolower($client);
    if ($client != $slug) {
        header("Location: /index.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously you can then edit the Client role as you see fit.

Comment: I guess my only question left is "is this secure?".